# Understanding the proof of the Lebesgue Covering Lemma.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

Here is the statement of the lemma and its proof (from Royden "Real Analysis 4th edition on pg.201 & 202").

> [image]
>   [image]

But I do not understand how the author applied the triangle inequality, specifically I do not understand the last paragraph, why we were in need of an index $k$? why we take $1/n_{k} < (r_{0}/2).$ Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in B(x_{n_k}, \frac{1}{n_k})$
$$d(x, x_0)\le d(x, x_{n_k} ) + d(x_{n_k}, x_0)\le  \frac{1}{n_k} + \frac{r_0}{2} < r_0$$

That's the application of the triangle inequality.

So  $x\in B(x_0, r_0)$, and consequently, $ B(x_{n_k}, \frac{1}{n_k}) \subset B(x_0, r_0)$

Comment: And why $d(x, x_{n_k} ) \le  \frac{1}{n_k}$?

Comment: @Emptymind See the first line. $x$ is chosen from the ball around $x_{n_k}$ with radius $1/n_k$.